# convert multiple single dimensional array to single multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 'N' single dimensional arrays(where N represents number of records retrieved by a sql command)
How do I convert it to multi dimensional array with keys as index?
At first I thought of creating a separate key array and then combining it with those N arrays

My output

```
Array ( [0] => PONDICHERRY [1] => 31-Jan-2018 [2] => [3] => distance and       height are not proportional. ) 
Array ( [0] => PONDICHERRY [1] => 03-Feb-2020 [2] => [3] => helloooooooooooooo )
```

My expected output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => PONDICHERRY [1] => 31-Jan-2018 [2] => [3] => distance and height are not proportional. ) [1] =>Array ( [0] => PONDICHERRY [1] => 03-Feb-2020 [2] => [3] => helloooooooooooooo )  )
```

It's difficult for me to combine the arrays, but how do i create like this?

Thank you

Comment: Two seperate arrays than use $arr[] =array_merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating N separate arrays and then combining them later, you can combine them already while reading the rows.

```
$results = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_row()){
  $results[] = $row;
}
// here you have $results in the expected output format
```

Comment: except the indices are strings instead of integer, your output would give something like this for me:
    
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [StationName] => PONDICHERRY [DOI] => 31-Jan-2018 [Remarks] => distance and height are not proportional. flask a [RainGauge] => ) [1] => Array ( [StationName] => PONDICHERRY [DOI] => 03-Feb-2020 [Remarks] => helloooooooooooooo [RainGauge] => ))